# Remove "None" text from pandas plot after using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following data:

```
d_data = {"Name":["Jean","Luis",   "Ana", "Ana",  "Jean",  "Luis","Ana",    "Ana",  "Luis","Ana","Luis" ],
          "Money":[100,   2220,       333,   3342,  4423,  43,   5454,     4455,    421,   996,3102],
          "Type":["Cash","Cash","Cash","Cash","Digital","Cash","Digital","Cash","Cash","Digital","Digital"]}
```

for which I want to make a bar plot for the type of money each person have. 
For that, I'm using this code:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(d_data)
df.groupby(["Name","Type"]).sum().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image]

From this plot I want to remove the double label in the legend: "None" and Money keeping just Type: "Digital" and "Cash"

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want to use `pivot_table` instead of `groupby` and `unstack`. That would not create any multiindex and as a side-effect not produce a strange legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

d_data = {"Name":["Jean","Luis",   "Ana", "Ana",  "Jean",  "Luis","Ana",    "Ana",  "Luis","Ana","Luis" ],
          "Money":[100,   2220,       333,   3342,  4423,  43,   5454,     4455,    421,   996,3102],
          "Type":["Cash","Cash","Cash","Cash","Digital","Cash","Digital","Cash","Cash","Digital","Digital"]}

df= pd.DataFrame(d_data)

pd.pivot_table(df, values="Money", index="Name", columns="Type", aggfunc="sum").plot(kind='bar', stacked=True) 

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to solve the issue. `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` returns you the legend handles and labels from the axis object. If you print `labels`, you will see `None, Type` is not printed.

Now, you can strip the labels to get only the "Cash" and "Digital" and store them using list comprehension in `labels_new`.

So when you set the legends again using `plt.legend(handles, labels_new)`, you only get the required legends. There might be other direct way but the following solution works too.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

d_data = {"Name":["Jean","Luis",   "Ana", "Ana",  "Jean",  "Luis","Ana",    "Ana",  "Luis","Ana","Luis" ],
          "Money":[100,   2220,       333,   3342,  4423,  43,   5454,     4455,    421,   996,3102],
          "Type":["Cash","Cash","Cash","Cash","Digital","Cash","Digital","Cash","Cash","Digital","Digital"]}

df= pd.DataFrame(d_data)
df.groupby(["Name","Type"]).sum().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax) 

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
labels_new = [label.strip('()').split(',')[1] for label in labels]
plt.legend(handles, labels_new)
```

[image]