# Pandas dataframe plot has "None, None" on the legend. How to get rid of them?

Tags: pandas, plot, legend

see attached picture. When I generate pandas dataframe plot, I see "None, None" on the legend. How to get rid of them?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp6kY.png)

Comment: Please read about how to format questions to include code, data and images inline.  You have a multi-level column index.  The names of each level of the MultiIndex are `None` and `None` (i.e. no names were provided).

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54356527/1609514